# Trouble with Finding Date Range in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataset which has a list of subjects, a start date, and an end date. I'm trying to do a loop so that for each subject I have a list of dates between the start date and end date. I've tried so many ways to do this based on previous posts but still having issues.

an example of the dataframe:

```
Participant #    Start_Date    End_Date
    1             23-04-19     25-04-19
```

An example of the output I want:

```
Participant #      Range    
      1           23-04-19
      1           24-04-19
      1           25-04-19
```

Right now my code looks like this:

```
subjs_490 = tracksheet_490['Participant #']
for subj_490 in subjs_490:
  temp_a = tracksheet_490[tracksheet_490['Participant #'].isin([subj_490])]  
  start = temp_a['Start_Date']
  end = temp_a['End_Date'
  start_dates = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(start), format = '%d-%m-%y')
  end_dates = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(end), format = '%d-%m-%y')
  date_range = pd.date_range(start_dates, end_dates).tolist()
```

With this method I'm getting the following error:

Cannot convert input [1   2016-05-03 Name: Start_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]] of type  to Timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Expanding ranges tends to be a slow process. You can create the `date_range` and then `explode` it to get what you want. Moving `'Participant #'` to the index makes sure it's repeated for all rows that are exploded.

```
df = (df.set_index('Participant #')
        .apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x.start_date, x.end_date), axis=1)  # :( slow
        .rename('Range') 
        .explode()
        .reset_index())
```

---

```
   Participant #      Range
0              1 2019-04-23
1              1 2019-04-24
2              1 2019-04-25
```

---

If you can't use `explode` another option is to create a separate DataFrame for each row and then `concat` them all together.

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Participant #': par, 'Range': pd.date_range(start, end)})
           for par,start,end in zip(df['Participant #'], df['start_date'], df['end_date'])], 
          ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: so should this replace the whole loop?

Comment: @code_newbie yes it can replace the entire loop if you just need the DataFrame of participants with each row being a date within the range. The apply axis=1 is still a loop over the rows so you haven't really removed the loop. But I don't think there's a way around looping in one way or another.

Comment: @ ALollz  thank you! I'm not getting an error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @code_newbie That was added in 0.24.0, a few versions ago. If you can I'd suggest upgrading. But I can provide an alternative too that doesn't use `explode`, give me a few minutes